# Preview post with image before confirming submission to server

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, preview

I have a page with a form that contains many fields and an image:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://project.dev/model/useradd" accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete="off" id="AddModel" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="yeq4iLVIyXiYyMbORaY5fA6zxIYDFWNJTqNVYiP9">   
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="material">Material</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="material" maxlength="30" style="width:30ch">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="color">Color</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="color" maxlength="10" style="width:20ch">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" maxlength="500">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="image">Picture</label>
    <input id="modelpic" name="image" type="file">
    <br/>
</div>
<div id="imagePreview" style="display: none;"></div> /** here I show the preview of the image through javascript */
<div class="form-group">
    <input id="AddBtn" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

here is the javascript that shows the image preview in the form after selection:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#modelpic').on("change", function () {

        //shows image preview in DOM
        var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];

        if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support

        if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
            var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]); // read the local file

            reader.onloadend = function(){ // show image in div
                $('#imagePreview').show().html('<img id="theImage" src="' +this.result+ '" class="img-fluid" alt="Your Image" />');

            }
        }
    })
});
```

What I need to do is show a preview of the post as it will appear before confirming submission.
How can I do it with jquery? My guess is I also have to modify the action part of the form code `action="http://project.dev/model/useradd"` in the html to something like self or something? Is it correct?
How do I get the submitted form data along the picture after hitting submit in jquery and use that to output the html to a preview div?

--- I also thinked to send the data to the server, save the image temporarily in public then load it in the preview. The problem is that if I use ajax to intercept the submission the image is not submitted. I think it's a problem of specyfing the data. My JS script code is like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("body").on("submit", "#AddModel", function (e) {

            var form = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                url: form.prop('action'),
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {

                console.log(data);


                },
                error: function (textStatus) {

                    {


                        var json = JSON.parse(textStatus.responseText);


                        console.log (json);


                    }

                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

I think this is wrong probably in the datatype or something.

Comment: To prevent the form from submitting use `.on("change", function (event) {  event.preventDefault();   ...`

Comment: ok but the javascript that I posted is not invoked after submit button is pressed but after image upload, to show the image that is going to be posted. So I guess I can leave the action part in the form and make a new JS using `$("body").on("submit", "#AddModel", function (e) { //  e.preventDefault();` ... what I need is getting the data from the form after submission along the image, show the preview and then confirm or abort.

Comment: I've not used a file reader in a while but the basic idea was that you capture the submit event, and build a preview of what the server output would look like using js before submitting the fields proper

Comment: another possibility would be to just go ahead and submit the form, and save the image in a temp location on the server, then redirect to a preview page where there user can choose to commit his changes permanently or upload an new image

Comment: I tried like that but the javascript somehow messes up the form submission and every field is being sumbitted but not the image.

Comment: the question here is how do you treat the data being submitted in javascript before invoking the server. Or better, how do you return this data from the server to the javascript after validation, in which form.